# Roles adding twice on react issue

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm currently creating an `on_raw_reaction_add` event where if a user adds a reaction to a message it will give them a role. I'm having a slight issue where when a user adds an emoji `if payload.emoji.id !=`it's adding two roles rather the role to the specific reaction.

This is happening regardless of the specific emoji IDs.

Help appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):  # Will be dispatched every time a user adds a reaction to a message the bot can se
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(572943295039406101)
    if not payload.guild_id:
        # In this case, the reaction was added in a DM channel with the bot
        return 

    if payload.message_id != 573104280299372556: # ID of the message you want reactions added to.
        return

    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  # You need the guild to get the member who reacted
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)  # Now you have the key part, the member who should receive the role

    if payload.emoji.id != 572943613554720789:
        lol = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="LoL")
        lol = discord.Object(559792606364565505)  # Pass the role's ID here
        await member.add_roles(lol, reason='Reaction role')  # Finally add the role to the member

    if payload.emoji.id != 572950778386317323:
        wow = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name="WoW")
        wow = discord.Object(558650247413235712)  # Pass the role's ID here
        await member.add_roles(wow, reason='Reaction role')  # Finally add the role to the member
```

Comment: So you have two conditionals in the code checking if the `payload.emoji.id` is not equal to some value.  Why wouldn't it be the case that both code blocks run if the emoji's ID doesn't match either of those values?  Have you tried passing in an emoji ID that is one of the two you check for in the example?  Or rather did you want your conditional to read `payload.emoji.id == 572950778386317323` so the roles is only added once?

Comment: I want the conditional to read `payload.emoji.id != 572950778386317323`  as that is the emoji the user should use to apply the role  `wow` for example.   `payload.emoji.id != 572950778386317323`  = 1️ digit emoji  

`payload.emoji.id == 57295077838631732` doesn't seem to work.

Here is a screenshot. https://pasteboard.co/IcGw7dH.png

Comment: Right.  So if I was a user and wanted the `WoW` role, I should use the emoji ID equal to `572950778386317323` right?  Then you should be checking if that user sent that in, not if they didn't.  The way your code reads right now, it says that if the user doesn't put the emoji ID `572943613554720789` in their payload, you are going to assign them the role of `LoL` and if they don't put the emoji ID `572950778386317323` you are going to give them the `WoW` role.  It seems like you have them reversed to me.  Does that make sense?

Comment: please replace the IDs in your code with human readable constants. your code would then read `if payload.emoji.id != SMILEY_FACE_EMOJI`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more general approach.  We maintain a mapping of reaction names to role names, then whenever someone reacts we look up their reaction in the dictionary and get the associated role:

```
emoji_role_map = {
    "1\N{COMBINING ENCLOSING KEYCAP}": "LoL",  # This is the default :one:
    "my_custom_emoji": "WoW"
}

@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload): 
    botroom = self.bot.get_channel(572943295039406101)
    if not payload.guild_id:
        # In this case, the reaction was added in a DM channel with the bot
        return 
    if payload.message_id != 573104280299372556: # ID of the message you want reactions added to.
        return
    guild = self.bot.get_guild(payload.guild_id)  # You need the guild to get the member who reacted
    member = guild.get_member(payload.user_id)  # Now you have the key part, the member who should receive the role
    role_name = emoji_role_map.get(payload.emoji.name)
    if role_name:  # None if not found
        role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role)
        await member.add_roles(role, reason='Reaction role')
```

This has a couple of advantages: you could load that map from anywhere, so you can decouple the role granting logic from the actual emojis and roles, you can now set this up on multiple servers and it will work as long as the names are the same, and you can now use default emojis to gain roles, which you couldn't using your system.

Comment: Can I use the same emojis for a different message with this method?

Comment: You could set up a dictionary of message IDs to dictionaries of emojis to roles